# How to use the test data from conftest.py in the test suite

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest

I'm writing an automation test suite in pytest framework. I'm adding a pytest fixture function in Conftest.py for test data importing (this fixture imports data from excel and generates me the test data). How to use the test data from conftest.py in the test suite.

(**Note**: *The Test Suite written is more of a pseudocode and not the actual code. Since my emphasis is more on the test parameterization & the data kindly ignore the test suite code.*).

## Conftest.py

```
import pytest
import openpyxl as xl

@pytest.fixture
def test_data():
    book = xl.load_workbook('../utils/testdata.xlsx', data_only=True)
    sheet=book.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
    max_rows=sheet.max_row
    max_columns=sheet.max_column

dataset=[]
temp=[]
for x in range(2,max_rows+1):
    for y in range(1,max_columns+1):
        val=sheet.cell(x,y)
        temp.append(val.value)
    dataset.append(temp)
    temp=[]
yield dataset
```

## Test_Suite:

```
import pytest
@pytest.mark.usefixtures('test_data')
class Test_main():
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("portal_code,DOB,user_name,pwd",dataset) # dataset from conftest.py
    def test_login(self,portal_code,DOB,user_name,pwd):
        login.enter_portal_code(portal_code)
        login.choose_DOB(DOB)
        login.enter_username(user_name)
        login.enter_pwd(pwd)
        login.click_login()
```

## Excel Content

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Either add the fixture as test argument and iterate over it inside the test, or load the test data globally so that it is available at load time to be passed to `parametrize`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add name of function from conftest.py to your case directly in suite
Example of suite:

```
import pytest
class Test_main():
    def test_login(self,test_data):
        """in your case the dict will be better"""
        login.enter_portal_code(test_data["key"]) #by key in dict
        login.choose_DOB(test_data["key"]) #by key in dict
        login.enter_username(test_data["key"]) #by key in dict
        login.enter_pwd(test_data["key"]) #by key in dict
        login.click_login()
```